# Missing dependancy information for jdbc.artifact.groupid:jdbc-driver:jar:1.0

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, maven-plugin, hbm2java

I am trying to use hbm2java maven plugins for hibernate. For mvn  hibernate3:hbm2cfgxml goal I am facing following error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app-hadoop 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2cfgxml (default-cli) @ my-app-hadoop >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2cfgxml (default-cli) @ my-app-hadoop <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2cfgxml (default-cli) @ my-app-hadoop ---
[WARNING] The POM for jdbc.artifact.groupid:jdbc-driver:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.454s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 28 11:14:20 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/6M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-   plugin:2.2:hbm2cfgxml (default-cli) on project my-app-hadoop: Ex
ecution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2cfgxml   failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-m
aven-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find  jdbc.artifact.groupid:jdbc-driver:jar:1.0 in htt
p://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval
of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I have added following plugin configuration in POM.xml to use hbm2java capabilities.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <components>
        <component>
          <name>hbm2ddl</name>
          <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
        </component>
        <component>
          <name>hbm2hbmxml</name>
          <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
        </component>
      </components>
      <componentProperties>
        <drop>true</drop>
        <configurationfile>/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
      </componentProperties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jdbc.artifact.groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Where would I find jdbc.artifact.groupid and what is missing in my pom.xml?

Comment: I am using oracle 11g 64bit on windows 7 64 machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must replace jdbc.artifact.groupid:jdbc-driver:1.0 by a real vendor artifact. For instance

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

if you use hsqldb.

**EDIT**

As you mention you use Oracle in your comment... The jdbc jar for Oracle db is provided with your Oracle distribution. You can also download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html).Once downloaded you will have to put it manually in your local maven repo (you can also store it in the thirparty repo of you Maven Repo Manager if you have one (Nexus, Archiva...). An other way is to add the dependency by using the `systemPath` declaration :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc6_g</artifactId>
   <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
   <systemPath>"C:/ThirpartyJars/Oracle/ojdbc6_g.jar"</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me by using local jar file from oracle installation

Comment: not it is giving me following error 14:10:55,550  WARN org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider - No connection properties specified - the user must supply JDBC
connections  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2cfgxml (default-cli) on project my-app-hadoop: Execution de
fault-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2cfgxml failed: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set -> [Help 1] even if added hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect in hibernate.properties.

Comment: it worked by adding hibernate.dialect in database.properties file.

Comment: however it not creating hibernate.cfg.xml i have mentioned all the required info in database.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your dependency

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>jdbc.artifact.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc-driver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

to

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
         <version>11.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
```